Unable to Bypass Cloudflare in Cloud Environment Scraping
Summary
I am trying to implement a scraping process that bypasses Cloudflare in an OCI environment, but I am not successful. It works in my local environment using several methods, but it fails in the cloud environment. Should I assume that OCI's IP addresses are blacklisted by Cloudflare??
If anyone has knowledge about this, I would appreciate your guidance.
What I've Tried
Scraping with Python

nodriver: Module
drissionpage: Module
flaresolverr: Docker proxy

Environment
Local

Machine: Mac mini with M2 chip
macOS: Sonoma 14.6.1

Cloud

OKE (Oracle Linux, ARM-based)
OCI Instance (Oracle Linux, ARM-based, Ubuntu)

Success/Failure
nodriver

Local: Successfully bypasses Cloudflare on Mac
Cloud: Fails to bypass Cloudflare on OCI instance (though the process finishes normally)

drissionpage

Local: Successfully bypasses Cloudflare on Mac
Cloud: Fails to bypass Cloudflare on OCI instance (though the process finishes normally)

flaresolverr

Local: Successfully bypasses Cloudflare by running Docker Compose to set up a proxy container and using the proxy in Python
Cloud (OKE): Fails to bypass Cloudflare with the proxy container running on a pod and Python using the proxy (process finishes normally)
Cloud (OCI Instance): Fails to bypass Cloudflare with the proxy container running on the instance and Python using the proxy (process finishes normally)

